# Item Counter with oval/elipse shape in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile, counter

What I'm trying to do is make a counter in Flutter which will be in this shape:

[image]

I'm fairly new regarding flutter and dart so I have tried to put this element inside of a Card but yeah I faced some issues due to overflow and it would be great if someone could give me a hint or point me to the right direction.

Here is my code for counter:

```
Card(child:Row(
        children: <Widget>[
           IconButton(icon:Icon(Icons.remove),onPressed: ()=>setState(()=>_itemCount--)),
           Text(_itemCount.toString()),
             IconButton(icon:Icon(Icons.add),onPressed: ()=>setState(()=>_itemCount++))
        ],
      ),);
```

Any help would be great, thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a container and add decoration to it.  Then inside the container use a row widget. In row use Iconbutton and text .

```
 Container(
   padding : EdgeInsets.all(7),
    decoration:BoxDecoration(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
      color: Colors.grey,
     ),
     child: Row(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
       children:[
          IconButton(.....),
          Text(......),
          IconButton(......),
       ]
     )
```

Comment: How do I center the Row inside that container because when I wrap it with center it doesent work also how do I define the width of that container so only the elements fit inside it. Cheers

Comment: If you define a specific width for the container it may have overflow issues on some devices. Now we have created a row and wrapped the row with a container and add padding to the container. This way when the row with increases the container also increases. To center the contents of row just below MainAxisSize.min write `mainAxisAlignment:MainAxisAlignment.Center,`

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a variable an assign it to the `Text` widget, not the function.
Increase

```
int theNumberThatIncreaseOrDecrease = 0;
```

The function that increments the number:

```
_itemCountIncrease() {
    setState(() {
        theNumberThatIncreaseOrDecrease += 1;
    });
}
```

The function that decreases the number:

```
_itemCountDecrease() {
    setState(() {
        theNumberThatIncreaseOrDecrease -= 1;
    });
}
```

Your card:

```
Card(
    child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.remove),
                onPressed: () => _itemCountIncrease(),
            ),
            Text(theNumberThatIncreaseOrDecrease.toString()),
            IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.add),
                onPressed: () => _itemCountDecreese(),
            ),
        ],
    ),
)
```